# Can a person go to jail for murdering a person that killed him before?

Tags: murder

This is a very hypothetical situation that has a very slim chance of occurring in real life. Suppose a person got murdered. Then, he/she gets revived and comes back to life and takes revenge on the murderer and kills the murderer. Can that person go to jail?

Comment: The person wasn't murdered, they were assaulted. If they were actually murdered, they can't be revived. "Stopped breathing" doesn't mean "actually legally dead". If they were superficially "dead" for a few minutes, they cannot legally seek retribution by killing their assailant.

Comment: So if the person actually came back to life it would be considered assault? Even if he was actually dead for a period of time? Again, this is hypothetical. This is the imaginary world.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "actually dead". Actual death is permanent.

Comment: Real legal systems don't deal with the imaginary world, and the legal systems in the imaginary world are themselves imaginary.  I'm afraid this question is one for [Worldbuilding.SE], not for [Law.SE].

Comment: I voted to close but retracted my vote because I realized that this question is actually answerable.

Comment: The legal system deals in fictions all the time to account for gaps, etc. This question is fine. In this scenario, yes, the person who was revived (whether or not he was "murdered") would be able to be prosecuted for murder. Self-defense must be used in the event of an immediate and unlawful use of force by another person. Thus, it specifically disallows acts of revenge (for obvious reasons). Considering the temporal issue here, e.g. I assume it would be several hours at least at the hospital before the person could take revenge, it would be premeditated and, thus, first-degree murder.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering my question. I'm writing a script for a film with this idea in it, so that's why I just asked this question. I want to make sure my story accurate in real life. Thank you for clarifying this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modern legal systems frown on individual retribution.  A victim of a crime is not allowed to punish the perpetrator of the crime; that falls to the state.  The answer is therefore *yes;* the person could be arrested, tried, and punished, including by imprisonment.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering my question. I'm writing a script for a film with this idea in it, so that's why I just asked this question. I want to make sure my story accurate in real life. Thank you for clarifying this.